# How to generate higher quality jpg plots on R

Tags: r, dataset, visualization, ggplot2

I have tried generating higher quality of data visualization plots from RStats. I tried increasing frame dimensions but it's still max at about ~350kb. How do I generate higher quality images from RStats?

Comment: What is the quality problem exactly? Is the resolution which too small? What kind of plot and how do you export it as an image? A small jpeg file size doesn't necessarily mean low quality, plots are often simple images which get compressed very well.

Comment: Yes, the resolution is small. ggplot graphs which I export as jpgs

Answer (score 0):

I think if you save the plot as SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) you can scale the image to any size. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226822/how-to-save-a-plot-made-with-ggplot2-as-svg) answer for an example.

Second, if you want to print larger, you might need to tweak the DPI (Dots per inch), as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711236/set-the-size-of-ggsave-exactly).